# jquery mobile table (Column toggle mode) - font-size change

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

how to increase font size properly in `jquery-mobile` table ( Column toggle mode)?
When I change body `font-size`, it doesn't work :

```
body {
font-size: 64px;
}
<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive"> data...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tg84trtw/2/

Comment: `body, .ui-table-columntoggle-btn.ui-mini { font-size: 64px; }`. http://jsfiddle.net/tg84trtw/4/

Comment: thank you Mujtaba! It has help me!